# How to not broken pipe when I redirect echo output on my program input and my program finishes?

Tags: bash, shell, echo

I have this `script.sh` :

```
while [ 1 ]
echo $(($RANDOM % 21))
done
```

I have my executable `./a.out` containing compiled C code which is a game and takes numbers between 1 and 20 on his input :

I test my game like that :

```
./script.sh | ./a.out
```

The game runs fine until it finishes and stops taking stdin arguments, and  :

```
echo: write error: Broken pipe
```

How to not broken pipe in this case ? How to get the information that I have to stop to echo ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*How to not broken pipe*"? Do you just want to hide the message?

Comment: No. I want to find a way to not broken pipe.

Comment: "broken pipe" is not a verb. What do you mean by "*to not broken pipe*"?

Comment: To not have this error happening.

Comment: @Davos: It kind of means `./allum1` exited pre-maturely when `./tmprandom.sh` had some data to write to the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that standard output is writable. If writing fails, exit the loop.

```
while true; do
    echo $((RANDOM % 21)) || exit
done
```

(Incidentally, `while [ 1 ]` probably doesn't do what you think. `[` aka `test` produces a true value if its argurent is not an empty string. It *works,* of course, but it's not a particularly elegant or idiomatic way to write `while true`.)

I can't reproduce your problem, but another common workaround is to disable the trap.

```
trap - SIGPIPE
```

(Maybe notice also that `RANDOM` doesn't need an explicit dollar sign in arithmetic context.)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately the solution `|| exit` doesn't work. It stills `echo: write error: Broken pipe`. I would like to find a way to prevent the script of broken piping. Or atleast to find a way to use again `echo` inside the script after it has broken piped.

Comment: When the output file descriptor is closed, there is no way for it to be reopened.

Comment: "Broken pipe" is a phrase composed of the past participle of the verb *break* and the noun *pipe.* The pipe breaks when the file descriptor is closed. The shell reports that this has happened in the past tense.

Comment: See updated answer now. I'm unable to repro but try `trap - SIGPIPE` at the top of your script.